# Number of Directed Acyclic Graphs with indegree at most one

Tags: graph-theory, trees

How many DAGs are there where every vertex has indegree at most one? If not known, is there a lower bound?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be such a DAG. $G$ must have at least one source, i.e., at least one vertex of indegree $0$. Let $R$ be the set of sources, and for each $r\in R$ let $G_r$ be the set of vertices reachable from $r$. Each $G_r$ is an [arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)). Add one new vertex $v_G$ with edges from $v_G$ to each $r\in R$ to get a new DAG $G'$; $G'$ is itself an arborescence. Conversely, deleting the root from an arborescence with at least two vertices leaves a DAG in which every vertex has indegree at most $1$.

The sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in [OEIS A000081](https://oeis.org/A000081) gives the number of unlabelled rooted trees with $n$ nodes; this is the same as the number of arborescences on $n$ nodes, so it’s the number of DAGs on $n-1$ nodes, all with indegree at most $1$. No closed form is given. There is an asymptotic result,

$$a_n\sim cd^nn^{-3/2}\;,$$

where $c=0.439924\ldots$ is [Otter’s asymptotic constant $\beta$](https://oeis.org/A187770), and $d=2.955765\ldots$ is [Otter’s rooted tree constant](https://oeis.org/A051491).

There is also a recurrence,

$$a_{n+1}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{d\mid k}da_d\right)a_{n-k+1}\;.$$

Comment: Very nice answer. (+1).

Comment: I added a proof of the recurrence relation. I see that in spite of you having provided an exemplary answer this question will probably be closed soon.

Comment: @Marko: Excellent! (It may survive: there are only two close votes so far, and I’d hope that most people would recognize it as a genuine question.)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to  the excellent answer by @BrianMScott by giving
a proof of the recurrence relation.   What we have here are forests of
rooted  trees.  Working  with  rooted  trees  we  obtain  the  species
$\mathcal{T}$ (multiset of trees attached to the root):

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \mathfrak{M}(\mathcal{T}).$$

This translates to the generating function

$$T(z) = 
z \exp\left(\sum_{l\le 1} \frac{T(z^l)}{l}\right).$$

Differentiate to obtain

$$T'(z) = 
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l)}{l}\right)
\\ + z \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l)}{l}\right)
\sum_{l\ge 1} T'(z^l) z^{l-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{z} T(z)
+ T(z) \sum_{l\ge 1} T'(z^l) z^{l-1}.$$

Extracting coefficients on $[z^n]$ yields

$$(n+1) T_{n+1} 
= T_{n+1} + 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} T_{n-q}
[z^q] \sum_{l\ge 1} T'(z^l) z^{l-1}
\\ = T_{n+1} + 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} T_{n-q}
\sum_{l\ge 1} [z^{q-(l-1)}] T'(z^l).$$

For the coefficient extractor to return a non-zero coefficient we must
have  $q = l-1+pl$  with $p\ge  0$ and  $l-1+lp\le n-1$  which implies
$p\le n/l-1.$ The result is

$$(n+1) T_{n+1} 
= T_{n+1} + 
\sum_{l\ge 1} \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/l\rfloor-1}
T_{n+1-l(p+1)}
[z^{pl}] T'(z^l)
\\ = T_{n+1} + 
\sum_{l=1}^{n} \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/l\rfloor-1}
(p+1) T_{p+1} T_{n+1-l(p+1)}.$$

This finally yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
T_{n+1} =  
\frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{l=1}^{n} \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/l\rfloor-1}
(p+1) T_{p+1} T_{n+1-l(p+1)}.}$$

Working to simplify this we first obtain

$$\frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{l=1}^{n} \sum_{p=1}^{\lfloor n/l\rfloor}
p T_{p} T_{n+1-lp}.$$

Now we are enumerating pairs $lp$ here where $1\le lp\le n$ so putting
$lp=k$ we may write this as

$$\frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{p|k}
p T_{p} T_{n+1-k}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
T_{n+1} =  
\frac{1}{n} 
\sum_{k=1}^{n} T_{n+1-k}
\sum_{p|k} p T_{p}.}$$

This is the form given in [OEIS A000081](https://oeis.org/A000081).

Answering  the question given  by the  OP we  return to  forests of
rooted trees and obtain the species $\mathcal{F}$ with equation

$$\mathcal{F}   =  \mathfrak{M}(\mathcal{T})$$   which  in   terms  of
generating functions yields

$$F(z) = T(z)/z.$$

This simply says that a forest is  in a bijection with a tree where we
attach the  trees to a new root  node.  Therefore a tree  on $n$ nodes
yields a forest  on $n-1$ nodes and we may use  $T_{n+1}$ to count the
DAGs that were being queried.